# java 8 - declare method to use in map, and pass the value to the method later on

Tags: lambda, functional-programming, java-8, function-pointers, functional-interface

I want to be able to declare methods in map to use up-front **BUT**, specify the parameter to pass to the function **NOT** when declaring the map and implementing the `FunctionalInterface`, but rather when using it.

Example - There's the method `DateTime.now().minusMinutes(int minutes)`. I want to put this method in map and call it based on some string key, **BUT** I want to specify the int minutes to pass to the method when using it. is that possible?

If possible, I would think it would look something like this:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface TimeFrame {
    DateTime createTimeFrame(int value);
}

private Map<String, TimeFrame> map = new HashMap<String, TimeFrame>() {{
        map.put("minutes", () -> DateTime.now().minusMinutes());
}}
```

and to use it, ideally, I want to pass the 4 to the `minusMinutes()` method

```
DateTime date = map.get("minutes").createTimeFrame(4);
```

Off course this is not compiling, but the idea is to declare the method up-front without the parameter, and pass the parameter to `minusMinutes()` later.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems what you are missing is adding the `int` parameter to the lambda expression :

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface TimeFrame {
    DateTime createTimeFrame(int value);
}

...

map.put("minutes", i -> DateTime.now().minusMinutes(i));
```

Now

```
DateTime date = map.get("minutes").createTimeFrame(4);
```

should work.

Comment: As a side note, this is the worst application of the double-curly brace anti-pattern, I’ve ever seen. It has a the negative impacts of that anti-pattern (creating an anonymous inner class with a reference to the outer instance), without even having the negligible advantage (saving the four letters `map.`). In fact, when you convert it to a clean initialization, i.e place a semicolon after `new HashMap<String, TimeFrame>()` and replace the double curly braces by single curly braces, it’s actually *shorter*.

Comment: Thinking about it again, accessing `map` from the initializer of the anonymous instance should even break with a `NullPointerException`, as the assignment to `map` would happen afterwards…

Comment: @Holger Agreed, though perhaps that should be a comment on the question, since I'm not sure if the OP of the question gets notified on comments to answers. I focused on the main issue in the question and therefore didn't change the double-curly brace code.

Comment: as far as I know, the OP gets notified.

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to define your lambda function a little differently.

```
map.put("minutes", (mins) -> DateTime.now().minusMinutes(mins))
```

`mins` is an argument that corresponds to the `value` in your functional interface. You can call it whatever you want; `mins` is just a suggestion.